# Looking for an ARD/ Unix command to clear firefox history/cache on a mac

Tags: macos, mac, terminal, firefox, apple-remote-desktop

I'm trying the following but not having any success in seeing anything cleared:

rm -R /Users//Library/Caches/Firefox/Profiles/.default/Cache

Thanks!

Comment: To see where Firefox is storing the disk cache, in the address bar type **about:cache** and press Enter.  Look at **Storage disk location:** under **disk** for the correct location. I'm running the latest, at this moment anyway, 44.0.2 and the location is: `$HOME/Library/Caches/Firefox/Profiles/*.default/cache2`

Comment: The History is kept in an SQL Database named **places.sqlite** and there may also be a write-ahead log file, named **places.sqlite-wal**, both located in: `"$HOME/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/*.default/"`

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking in the wrong folder.  The more recent versions of Firefox put it here.  You may want to alter your command slightly to delete folders as well.

```
rm -rf /Users/<username>/Library/Caches/Firefox/Profiles/<xxx>.default/cache2
```

Comment: To see where Firefox is storing the disk cache, in the address bar type **about:cache** and press Enter.  Look at **Storage disk location:** under **disk** for the correct location.  I'm running the latest, at this moment anyway, 44.0.2 and the location is: `$HOME/Library/Caches/Firefox/Profiles/*.default/cache2`

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help. I believe that I am having some success, but come with another question. This seems to do the ticket:

rm -rf /Users/*/Library/Caches/Firefox/Profiles/*.default/cache2

I was able to verify using about:cache (under disk) that the # of entries decreased after running the script. However, is there a way that this would also clear the browsing history? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I adjusted my path to cache2.  As mentioned in a comment above, history is stored in that places.sqllite file.  http://kb.mozillazine.org/Places.sqlite